# modal popup with form having no border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
        if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
            var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
            document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');
        }
    }

    // Close modal window with 'data-dismiss' attribute or when the backdrop is clicked
    if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');
        modal.classList.remove('open');
    }
}, false);
```

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-window {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.modal-window.small {
    width: 30%;
}

.modal-window.large {
    width: 75%;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}


.form-group .form-control {
    border: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#009688), to(#009688)), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#D2D2D2), to(#D2D2D2));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#009688, #009688), -webkit-linear-gradient(#D2D2D2, #D2D2D2);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#009688, #009688), -o-linear-gradient(#D2D2D2, #D2D2D2);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#009688, #009688), linear-gradient(#D2D2D2, #D2D2D2);
    -webkit-background-size: 0 2px, 100% 1px;
    background-size: 0 2px, 100% 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom, center -webkit-calc(100% - 1px);
    background-position: center bottom, center calc(100% - 1px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: background 0s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background 0s ease-out;
    transition: background 0s ease-out;
    float: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-round btn-info1" data-target="modal" data-toggle="modal">DONATE</button>

<div id="modal" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-window">
                    <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Bank Details</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">Name of Account:</span> Shyamchi Aai Foundation</p>
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">Account Number:</span> 913010042120913</p>
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">IFSC Code:</span> UTIB0000104</p>
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">Bank Address:</span> Business Square Plot No-57, Mayur Colony, Next To Jog High School, Kothrud</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">Bank Name:</span> Axis Bank Ltd.</p>
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">Account type:</span> SB-TRUST/SOCIETY/NGO/GOVT</p>
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">MICR Code:</span> 411211004</p>
                            <p class="text-color"><span class="text-muted">Branch:</span> KOTHRUD</p><br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <h2>Donor Details</h2>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" name="Phone">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" name="Address">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PAN" name="PAN">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" name="Amount">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose" name="Purpose">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="">Cheque
                                </label>
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="">NEFT
                                </label>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-round">SUBMIT</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: design for the modal popup]
popup modal code its working fine on my system i have posted proper code here.my problem is about css,i want to design the same page as displayed in the image.but not getting the proper effect like checkbox is not selecting,text is not proper layout,etc...

Comment: The code you posted does do or show anything but a _Donate_ button

Comment: @Lakhan you have jquery library in your code. but you are not using it. why?

Comment: i have used it but the problem i am facing now is checkbox is not selecting & if i set checked property to the checkbox its not going to unchecked

Answer (score 0):

you may not use  it 'border'，so the 'model' no border.